# Struggling with LSB and MSB in javascript

Tags: javascript, endianness, binary-data

Normally the specification of a format explains how to binary data must be read. Many times it is just [Little Endian or Big Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). This is quite simple because, at least Javascript, allows to read data in each format.

Endianness indicates the order of bytes, but there is also LSB and MSB (for each endianness) which indicates the order of bits.

For example, my current "map" talks about numbers stored using 2's complement, LSB.

Is this just reading it as an [Integer of 16 bits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getInt16https://) ? I don't see in any documentation whether Javascript uses LSB or MSB or whether this can even be changed? Any help?

Comment: I've never seen any data format where individual bytes were in LSB order. I think you can assume it's always MSB, regardless of endian-ness.

Comment: JavaScript does not give direct access to bytes, except in the case of ArrayBuffer. ArrayBuffer uses the same endianness as the underlying platform, but you can use DataView to choose the endianness.